# Defining method template separately from its declaration

Tags: c++, templates

The following example code does not compile:

```
#include <iostream>

template<bool Enable>
struct BaseTemplate
{

 template< typename Policy>
 void templateMethod(Policy& policy);
};


template<bool Enable>
template<typename Policy>
void BaseTemplate<Enable>::templateMethod<Policy>(Policy& policy)
{
        std::cout << "template method" << std::endl;
};


int main()
{
BaseTemplate<true> base;
float v = 3.0;
base.templateMethod(v);
};
```

It fails with this error:

```
$ g++-4.8 -std=c++11 mtempl.cpp -o ./xMtempl
mtempl.cpp:15:65: error: function template partial specialization ‘templateMethod<Policy>’ is not allowed
 void BaseTemplate<Enable>::templateMethod<Policy>(Policy& policy)
```

Now, this is the thing that annoys me: **this is not a specialization**, I'm just defining the method template separately from the declaration!

If I replace

```
template<bool Enable>
template<typename Policy>
void BaseTemplate<Enable>::templateMethod<Policy>(Policy& policy)
{
        std::cout << "template method" << std::endl;
};
```

with this

```
template<bool Enable, typename Policy>
void BaseTemplate<Enable>::templateMethod<Policy>(Policy& policy)
{
        std::cout << "template method" << std::endl;
};
```

The error I get is:

```
mtempl.cpp:16:65: error: template-id ‘templateMethod<Policy>’ in declaration of primary template
 void BaseTemplate<Enable>::templateMethod<Policy>(Policy& policy)
                                                                 ^
mtempl.cpp:16:6: error: prototype for ‘void BaseTemplate<Enable>::templateMethod(Policy&)’ does not match any in class ‘BaseTemplate<Enable>’
 void BaseTemplate<Enable>::templateMethod<Policy>(Policy& policy)
      ^
mtempl.cpp:9:7: error: candidate is: template<bool Enable> template<class Policy> void BaseTemplate<Enable>::templateMethod(Policy&)
  void templateMethod(Policy& policy);
```

What's the problem? **How do I define the method template separately from the declaration?**

Comment: Did you read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file

Comment: Have you tried e.g. `template<bool Enable> template<typename Policy> void BaseTemplate<Enable>::templateMethod(Policy& policy)`? Just like other templated functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
template<bool Enable>
template<typename Policy>
void BaseTemplate<Enable>::templateMethod<Policy>(Policy& policy)
{
    // stuff
};
```

*This* is a specialization. Remove `<Policy>` to have a simple definition.

```
template<bool Enable>
template<typename Policy>
void BaseTemplate<Enable>::templateMethod(Policy& policy)
{
    // stuff
};
```

BTW, you've extra semicolons at the end of methods.